# Axios get request not change corresponding to back-end

Tags: javascript, axios

React

```js
class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      authen: "None"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.word)
        if (res.data.word === "loggedin") {
          this.setState({
            authen: "LoggedIn"
          })
        } else if (res.data.word === "pleaselogin") {
          this.setState({
            authen: "SignIn"
          })
        }
      })
  }
}
```

Server.js

```js
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.loggedin) {
    var obj = JSON.parse('{"word":"loggedin"}');
    res.send(obj)
  } else {
    var obj = JSON.parse('{"word":"pleaselogin"}');
    res.send(obj)
  }
  res.end();
});
```

[image]

After I logged in > the localhost:5000 change the json data to {"word":"loggedin"} but in the front-end > data still console.log>please login .

I have tried in changing the language of send data but i don't know why

Thankyou vary much

Comment: you know that you can send an json back like this `res.json({ word: "loggedin" })`

Comment: How is the session handled in the backend? With cookies? Are the cookies sent in the ajax request' Try `axios.get("http://localhost:5000/", {withCredentials: true})`, maybe it'll work

Comment: your question is not completed. 
We don't know about your session stage.
And don't parse and send data

Just send the data as JSON

Comment: @KhantMinSiThu Thank you for helping, I'll clarify more in question. My code process is sending the json data from localhost:5000 to localhost:3000 by axios but when i've logged in > the json data word changing from please login to loggedin but the front-end didn't change corresponding to the back-end (The session is cookies)

Answer (score 0):

The componentDidMount() method runs after the component output has been rendered to the DOM.

- If you want to check auth like that so you must create child component and do it from there

=> Because when this component act login , it will update component (render) so it will render the child component .

=> You can research life circle of reactjs in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)